How to use custom data array for plot in egui_plot
I am trying to use an array with my own data, but every method i have tried has errored in some way
Here is the Code:
// Destiny Telemetry App
#![cfg_attr(not(debug_assertions), windows_subsystem = "windows")] // hide console window on Windows in release
#![allow(rustdoc::missing_crate_level_docs)] // it's an example

use eframe::egui::{self};
use egui_plot::{Plot, Legend};



fn main() -> eframe::Result {
    let options = eframe::NativeOptions::default();
    eframe::run_native(
        "Destiny Telemetry",
        options,
        Box::new(|_cc| Ok(Box::<MultiPlotApp>::default())),
    )
}

struct MultiPlotApp;

impl Default for MultiPlotApp {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Self
    }
}

impl eframe::App for MultiPlotApp {
    fn update(&mut self, ctx: &egui::Context, _: &mut eframe::Frame) {
        egui::CentralPanel::default().show(ctx, |ui| {
            ui.heading("Telemetry from Destiny");
            ui.separator();

            // Top row: 3 plots
            ui.horizontal(|ui| {
                for i in 1..=3 {
                    ui.vertical(|ui| {
                        ui.label(format!("Plot {}: {}", i, plot_description(i)));
                        ui.group(|ui| {
                            Plot::new(format!("plot_{}", i))
                                .allow_zoom(true)
                                .allow_drag(true)
                                .allow_scroll(true)
                                .legend(Legend::default())
                                .height(265.0)
                                .width(405.0)
                                .show(ui, |plot_ui| {
                                    let line = generate_plot_data(i);
                                    plot_ui.line(line);
                                });
                        });
                    });
                }
            });

            ui.separator();

            // Bottom row: 3 plots
            ui.horizontal(|ui| {
                for i in 4..=6 {
                    ui.vertical(|ui| {
                        ui.label(format!("Plot {}: {}", i, plot_description(i)));
                        ui.group(|ui| {
                            Plot::new(format!("plot_{}", i))
                                .allow_zoom(true)
                                .allow_drag(true)
                                .allow_scroll(true)
                                .legend(Legend::default())
                                .height(265.0)
                                .width(405.0)
                                .show(ui, |plot_ui| {
                                    let line = generate_plot_data(i);
                                    plot_ui.line(line);
                                });
                        });
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    }
}


/// Generate data dynamically for each plot
fn generate_plot_data(index: usize) -> egui_plot::Line {
    
    let g_1 = vec![];
    
    
    
    // Define the function for each plot
    let func = match index {
        1 => |g_1: f64| g_1.sin(),  // Plot 1: sine wave
        2 => |g_2: f64| g_2.cos(),  // Plot 2: cosine wave
        3 => |g_3: f64| g_3.tan(),  // Plot 3: tangent wave
        4 => |g_4: f64| g_4.sinh(), // Plot 4: hyperbolic sine wave
        5 => |g_5: f64| g_5.cosh(), // Plot 5: hyperbolic cosine wave
        6 => |g_6: f64| g_6.tanh(), // Plot 6: hyperbolic tangent wave
        _ => |_base_g: f64| 0.0,     // Default
    };

    // Generate data points manually
    let values: Vec<[f64; 2]> = (0..100)
        .map(|i| {
            let x = i as f64 * 0.1; // Adjust step size
            let y = func(x);
            [x, y]
        })
        .collect();

    // Create a Line with the generated values
    egui_plot::Line::new(values)
}

/// Returns a description for each plot based on its index
fn plot_description(index: usize) -> &'static str {
    match index {
        1 => "Sine Wave",
        2 => "Cosine Wave",
        3 => "Tangent Wave",
        4 => "Hyperbolic Sine",
        5 => "Hyperbolic Cosine",
        6 => "Hyperbolic Tangent",
        _ => "Unknown Plot",
    }
}

In the generate_plot_data() function i want to change the x.sin and so on to be my own array for x and y coordinates
In the future these arrays will be data recieved over serial and plotted
I have tried using AI to solve the problem but every solution they gave just created more errors
